# Connecting to socket.io from client hosted via php gear? - openshift

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I'm trying to do something relatively simple, well at least to get things started. I have two gears hosted on **openshift**, a **php-5.4** and a **node.js** gear.  My client side file is hosted from the php gear, but i'm trying to setup a **socket.io** connection to the node server.

I realize this brings up CORS issues
I've tried updating the headers among (many) other things without luck.  For the sake of testing i'm just using the socket.io [chat example](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

I keep getting this error:

```
GET http://www.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416040246016-0 404 (Not Found)`
```

It does work if I connect from the index.html file hosted via express.

I'm relatively new to node, so please excuse if I made some blunder in my assumptions about how to approach this problem.

So here is the code.

**Server side:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var server = function(){

var strt = this;

strt.setHeaders = function(){

  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.domain.com:8000,
    http://domain.com:8000, http://node-domain.rhcloud.com:8000');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    next();
  });
}

strt.setupVariables = function() {
  strt.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
  strt.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

  if (typeof strt.ipaddress === "undefined") {

      console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
      strt.ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
  };
}

strt.createRoutes = function() {

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });

}

strt.ioServer = function() {
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
  });
}

strt.initializeServer = function() {

  http.listen(strt.port, strt.ipaddress, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8000');
  });
}

}

var Start = new server();
Start.setHeaders();
Start.setupVariables();
Start.createRoutes();
Start.ioServer();
Start.initializeServer();
```

**Client Side:**

```
<script src="http://node-metagenome.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io().connect("http://node-domain.rhcloud.com:8000");
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  It was a relatively small change.

**Instead of:**

```
var socket = io().connect("http://node-domain.rhcloud.com:8000");
```

**It should be:**

```
var socket = io("http://node-domain.rhcloud.com:8000");
```

It also turns out I don't need to set headers either.